# How to create a CActiveDataProvider from a slave Model when using multiple databases

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to create a `PBBG` application. ( where pbbg stands for persistent browser based game )

Because there will be involved multiple servers I want for each server a db.

In order to write data to a slave db, I just save a `int value` into a static property, like:

```
    public static function allocate_new_village() {
        VillageSlaveM::$server_id = Yii::app()->session['user_active_world'];//1,2,3,4,5,...
        $model_village_slave_m = new VillageSlaveM();
        $model_village_slave_m->x = 1;
        $model_village_slave_m->y = 1;
        $model_village_slave_m->k = 1;
        $model_village_slave_m->name = 'standard';
        $model_village_slave_m->user_id = 1;
        if ($model_village_slave_m->validate() && $model_village_slave_m->save()) {
//            echo 1;
        } else {
//            echo 2;
        }
    }
```

The following example, creates a `CActivedataProvider` by using the main db:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Village');
        $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ));
```

How do I create a `CActiveDataProvider` by using a slave db and the `VillageSlaveM` model?

```
<?php

class VillageSlaveM extends Village {

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static $server_id = 1;
    public static $master_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        //echo __FUNCTION__;
        //die;
        //echo 111;
        self::$master_db = Yii::app()->{"db" . self::$server_id};
        if (self::$master_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$master_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$master_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, at first it did not worked, now it does:

```
VillageSlaveM::$server_id = Yii::app()->session['user_active_world'];
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('VillageSlaveM');
$this->render('index', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
```